# TypeError: (depth0 || container.hooks.helperMissing).call is not a function

Tags: node.js

**I was doing a shopping cart project in node js.When I accidently cleared the title name after 'this.'I faced this error.**

```
{{this.}}
{{this.Price}}
{{this.Description}}
```

Answer (score 3):

When I corrected the code like this the error was gone.

```
{{this.title}}
{{this.Price}}
{{this.Description}}
```